# Differences between InteractiveInterpreter.runcode and the exec function?

Tags: python, exec

I have this piece of code:

```
import code

interpreter = code.InteractiveInterpreter()
myCode = code.compile_command('if True: print("IT\'S TRUE!!")')
interpreter.runcode(myCode)
```

I'm wondering, what is the difference between `InteractiveInterpreter.runcode()` and a normal `exec()` function? The code above doesn't work, but this one does:

```
exec("if True: print('IT\'S TRUE!!')")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import code
>>> 
>>> interpreter = code.InteractiveInterpreter()
>>> myCode = code.compile_command('if True: print("IT\'S ONE!!")')
>>> interpreter.runcode(myCode)
TypeError: exec: arg 1 must be a string, file, or code object
```

It's obvious that `interpreter.runcode` accept string or code.

But `myCode` is None.

```
>>> myCode
>>>
```

According to [`code.compile_command` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html#code.compile_command):

> ...
>   Returns a code object (the same as compile(source, filename, symbol))
>   if the command is complete and valid; **None if the command is
>   incomplete**; raises SyntaxError if the command is complete and contains
>   a syntax error, or raises OverflowError or ValueError if the command
>   contains an invalid literal.

If you pass a string to `interpreter.runcode`, it works.

```
>>> interpreter.runcode('if True: print("IT\'S ONE!!")')
IT'S ONE!!
```

Comment: so `myCode` isn't a file object?

Comment: @aIKid, It's is `None`, not a file object.

Comment: Sorry, typo. I mean, it's not a code object? I thought `code.compile_command()` should return a code object.

Comment: @aIKid, If you do `code.compile_command('if True: print("IT\'S ONE!!")\n')`, you will get code object. (Appending newline character)